# How to pass a list of elements as parameter in Jersey?

Tags: java, jersey

Is there a way to pass a list of elements as a parameter to a method using Jersey?

I have the class `Sample` annotated with `@XmlRootElement` with the following variables: `idUsuario`, `x`, and `timestamp`.

In my `MedicaoResource` class, the method:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/xml")
public List<Medicao> getMedicoes() {
    return new ArrayList<Medicao>(getAllMedicoes());
}
```

returns something like:

```
<medicaoes>
    <medicao>
        <idUsuario>1</idUsuario>
        <timestamp>2012-04-16T12:25:00.454-03:00</timestamp>
        <x>0.71</x>
    </medicao>
    <medicao>
        <idUsuario>1</idUsuario>
        <timestamp>2012-04-16T12:25:00.454-03:00</timestamp>
        <x>1.71</x>
    </medicao>
</medicaoes>
```

**Now, I would like to do something like this:**

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces("text/plain")
public String addMedicoes(ArrayList<Medicao> medicoes) {
    for (Medicao medicao : medicoes) {
        addMedicao(medicao);
    }
    return "success";
}
```

**How would I have to write my XML for the method above to work properly? I have tried passing the same XML that the method `getMedicoes` returns, but it won't work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use type `List<Medicao>` instead of `ArrayList` in the `addMedicoes` method.
This is probably what was preventing jersey/jaxb to properly unmarshall your xml query.

Besides, you should post more information apart from `won't work`, because with just that, we can only guess what's wrong. What does not work ? Do you have any error message/log to show. What exactly did you try?

Comment: After a long afternoon trying, I realized I had two methods that consumed XML. So that was probably the reason why it wouldn't work. When the XML arrived, the wrong method was called. When I removed the one method that I didn't need, it worked fine. And you're right, I had to use `List`.